# HTML: change background row base on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a `table` in `HTML` page and I want to color all the row in red when its first column gets a particular value.

I read something about that on **`StackOverflow`** and I added these two attributes (border-collapse and border-spacing) to my table

```
<table id="my-table" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0 1px">
```

Now, in my JavaScript function, how can I set the background color in base of new value?

I tryied with theese:

```
 if (value == 'broken') {my-table[i].css('background-color','red');} // OR   
 if (value == 'broken') {my-table[i].cells.style.background = 'red';}
```

where i is the index of the row I'm considering for. Nothing changes! Anyone can give me an advice? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the rest of the relevant source code? Where is `value` defined?

Comment: Actually I don't think it's relevant for my question. The Value is returned by an AJAX request that when it 's executed successfully calls a method and there the code lines I wrote are executed.

Comment: It would be relevant to the question - if you had written code that did not cause syntax errors in the first place. So you start by checking what the browser console tells you first of all now.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById` and use a variable, it'll make life easier

e.g.

```
 var bgtable = document.getElementById("my-table").getElementsByTagName("tr");
 bgtable[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Also check your console for any errors and check that `i` 1) is being filled and 2) has the correct value.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, I don't want to color all the table but only the row.

Comment: you still should use getElementbyId. I added the [i] which i presumed pointed to the row index. (p.s. this is not a code-writing service, SO is for guidance)

Answer (score 0):

The following sample demonstrates a walk through an table...

you can adapt this to your sample...

You can also use the table Object...

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table key´s</title>
    <style>
      td{width:10px;height:10px;background:#ddd;}
      tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(5){background:#f00;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
    </div>
    <script>    
      var row=col=5,max=10;
      tableContainer.innerHTML = '<table>'+('<tr>'+'<td>'.repeat(max)).repeat(max)+'</table>';
      window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        var colDiff, rowDiff;
        var keyMap = new Map([[37,[-1,0]],[38,[0,-1]],[39,[1,0]],[40,[0,1]]]);
        if (keyMap.has(e.keyCode)){
          document.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${row}) td:nth-child(${col})`).style.background='#ddd';
          [colDiff,rowDiff]=keyMap.get(e.keyCode);
          row+=rowDiff;
          col+=colDiff;
          row = (row>max) ? max : (row < 1) ? 1 : row;
          col = (col>max) ? max : (col < 1) ? 1 : col;
          document.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${row}) td:nth-child(${col})`).style.background='#f00';
        }
      }) 
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to style a particular row's background color you need to set the css on the `tr` element. Without more context on where `value` is defined I can't really give you a specific code example.

Here is an example where I decide if a row is "broken" based on a data attribute set on the `tr`:

```js
$("tbody tr", $("#my-table")).each(function() {
  var tr = $(this);

  if (tr.data("broken") == true) {
    tr.css({
      "background-color": "red"
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0 1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-broken="true">
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```